# When I login in Yahoo Mail, I am logged out automatically from Messenger. How to stop that?

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-mail, yahoo-messenger

When I login in Yahoo Mail, I am logged out automatically from Messenger (the real one).
That's because I appear in Yahoo Mail Chat list.
How to stop that, that is how to stop being logged out from Messenger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sign out from the messenger in Yahoo Mail. Click the yellowish lightning icon next to `Online Contacts` (it's grey in the screenshot because I'm signed out).

[image: yahoo mail messenger sign out]

Comment: The problem was that you had to do that any time you login in Mail. I tried several times and at some point appeared a window "logout of messenger here or external Messenger". Then I checked "remember the choice". That eventually solved the problem.

Comment: The full settings are accessible through `Options -> Messenger options` on top-left of Yahoo Mail. The first tab that opens is called `General`. There's a setting called `Sign Out` in the middle of it. Set it to `Always sign out here` & click OK.

Comment: for some reason when I click on Messenger Options, nothing happens

Comment: now the Messenger Options works

Answer (score -3):

Yes, permanently sign out and close the web site.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer a bit, it is not very helpful at present.